# Etherscan internal transactions

Tags: transactions

I sent ETH from ED to my ledger. The coins never made it. IN Etherscan I  can see the internal transactions (whatever that is). Is there a way to retrieve  the ETH from the transactions?

https://etherscan.io/address/0x7228540deb07F45a562203F3Cb185f079E88b16d#internaltx

Comment: care to post the Etherscan link, we might be able to debug a bit

Comment: I have the same issue - send 2 ETH to Kucoin but deposit never arrived (6 days ago). Etherscan is showing the correct amount but the transaction is only showing as internal transaction. https://etherscan.io/address/0x897fea351e5d8f1d13c51a39ee02b4a0e2c0500d Thanks for any help!!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18333)

Comment: Thanks for the help..      https://etherscan.io/address/0x7228540deb07F45a562203F3Cb185f079E88b16d#internaltx

Comment: This address has 2 ether...it's fine if it transfers as an internal one.  My guess is you don't have the key to this address right?

Comment: Can some one comment how did the internal transaction to transaction issue resolved ? How long does it took to resolve it ?

Comment: It was never resolved. I guess nobody  has any knowledge on this situation. At least I tried  its only money right, lol